# MYSQL values including Nulls are being returned

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to build a database and one of the tables is causing me grief.

I would like to output all the values in the table including those that have Null values.

```
CREATE TABLE engine (
    engineid INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dualfuel TINYINT  DEFAULT 0, -- new style for 
    primaryfuelid INT NOT NULL,
    secondaryfuelid INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (engineid),
    FOREIGN KEY (primaryfuelid) REFERENCES fueltype(fueltypeid),
    FOREIGN KEY (secondaryfuelid) REFERENCES fueltype(fueltypeid)
);

INSERT INTO engine VALUES
(0, 1, NULL),
(0, 2, NULL),
(0, 3, NULL),
(0, 4, NULL),
(1, 1, 4),
(1, 2, 4);
```

and the other table is

```
CREATE TABLE FuelType (
    fueltypeid INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fueltypename VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (fueltypeid)
    );

INSERT INTO fueltype (fueltypename)
VALUES 
    ('Petrol'),
    ('Diesel'),
    ('Gas'),
    ('Electric');
```

The Select statement is as follows:

```
select e.engineid
     , e.dualfuel
     , e.primaryfuelid
     , e.secondaryfuelid
     , f.fueltypename 1st
     , s.fueltypename 2nd
  From engine e
  join fueltype f
     , fueltype s
 where e.primaryfuelid = f.fueltypeid
   and e.secondaryfuelid = s.fueltypeid
   and f.fueltypeid < s.fueltypeid
 order 
    by (engineid);
```

The output is as follows
[image]

What i am trying to do is to get all the entries in the table including those that are null.
I know that it is a logical issue.

Comment: Change `join fueltype f, fueltype s` to `LEFT join fueltype f, fueltype s`.

Comment: Note that, while not 'reserved', 'engine' is a keyword in MySQL, so possibly best avoided asa a table/column identifier.

Comment: And don't mix implicit and explicit join styles.

Comment: ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1  (for table `engine`)

Comment: You are referening to the same column for both foreign keys, not something that I would do without a join clause......

Comment: your are mixing joins and comma sepreated tableare alwayws cross joined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing two left joins:

```
select e.engineid, e.dualfuel, e.primaryfuelid, e.secondaryfuelid
    fp.fueltypename as fueltype1,
    fs.fueltypename as fueltype2
from engine e
left join fueltype fp on fp.fueltypeid = e.primaryfuelid
left join fueltype fs on fs.fueltypeid = e.secondaryfuelid
order by e.engineid
```

Notes:

- Don't mix implicit and explicit joins! Use standard, explicit joins consistently
- An identifier can't start with a digit, unless it is quoted - save yourself that complication by using compliant column aliases
- engine is a [languange keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), hence not a good choice for a column name